# Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage revert to default value

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How to reset the custom error page value to default through power shell for sharepoint webapplication?

I have the below script to change it "Blank". But I am not sure, if this is equal to default value.

```
Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage -identity Signout -RelativePath " " -WebApplication WebAppURL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [powershell command documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607768%28v=office.15%29.aspx). There is a "Reset" switch:

> Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage -identity "Signout" -Reset -WebApplication
>   "WebAppURL"